# How to create equally sized square Composables in a Row with no white lines between them?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm building an app where I need to display a row of square tiles, each of a different color. I've created a Composable ColorTile that takes the tile's name and color code as parameters, and a ColorTilesRow Composable that takes the name and a list of color codes.

The problem is that the first two tiles in the row have a slightly smaller height than the others, causing white lines to appear between them and the next tiles. All tiles are supposed to be equally sized squares.

I've tried various modifications to the ColorTile and ColorTilesRow Composables, including setting aspect ratio and fillMaxWidth properties, and using weight and fillMaxSize modifiers in the Row, but I still can't get all the tiles to be exactly the same size.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

[image]

Here's the relevant code:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun ColorTile(name: String, color: String) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(1f),
        color = Color(color.toColorInt()),
        onClick = { }) {

       
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ColorTilesRow(name: String, colors: List<String>) {
    Row {
        colors.forEach { color ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(1f)) {
                ColorTile(name, color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get all the tiles to be exactly the same size and avoid white lines between them?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making an extensive function for `LazyGridItemScope` and using that in a `LazyVerticalGrid`.

> ***ColorTile***

```
@Composable
fun LazyGridItemScope.ColorTile(
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier,
    name : String,
    color : String
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier,
        color = Color(color.toColorInt())
    ) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Then in your UI composable, call the function in a `LazyVerticalGrid` as follows.

```
@Composable
fun ColorTilesGrid(
    modifier : Modifier = Modifier,
    name : String,
    colors : List<String>
) {
    // columns = GridCells.Adaptive(dp size of each cell) or GridCells.Fixed(fixed number of cells)
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = modifier,
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(4),
    ) {
        items(colors) { color ->
            ColorTile(
                modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(1f),
                name = name,
                color = color,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1):

The **Modifier** you apply to the **Box** does not work on the **ColorTile**. So you need to change the Composable as follows and pass modifier to **ColorTile** instead of passing it to the **Box**:

```
@Composable
fun ColorTile(
    name: String,
    color: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Surface(
        color = Color(color.toColorInt()),
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

And also using **Row**s as representation of **Grid** can affect the optimization of the app, so in your case I would recommend using this solution with **VerticalGrid**:

```
@Composable
fun ColorTileGrid(name: String, colors: List<String>) {
    VerticalGrid(columns = 4) {
        colors.forEach { color ->
            ColorTile(
                name = name,
                color = color,
                modifier = Modifier.aspectRatio(1f)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you still want the Rows solution then ask me, I can write it, but it is inefficient.

**Edit:**
Google util function for VerticalGrid:

```
@Composable
fun VerticalGrid(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    columns: Int = 2,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        content = content,
        modifier = modifier
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        val itemWidth = constraints.maxWidth / columns

        val itemConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth = itemWidth,
            maxWidth = itemWidth
        )

        val placeables = measurables.map { it.measure(itemConstraints) }

        val columnHeights = Array(columns) { 0 }
        placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
            val column = index % columns
            columnHeights[column] += placeable.height
        }
        val height = (columnHeights.maxOrNull() ?: constraints.minHeight)
            .coerceAtMost(constraints.maxHeight)
        layout(
            width = constraints.maxWidth,
            height = height
        ) {
            val columnY = Array(columns) { 0 }
            placeables.forEachIndexed { index, placeable ->
                val column = index % columns
                placeable.placeRelative(
                    x = column * itemWidth,
                    y = columnY[column]
                )
                columnY[column] += placeable.height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i access VerticalGrid? I only have LazyVerticalGrid available... Also i have just 8 rows and and animatedvisibility for each so I have no idea how to make this work. One other problem is when LazyGrid was placed on a scrollable column app just crashed despite userscroll disabled.
I'd be glad to hear how can i fix optimization and else 

I've added additional screenshot in my post

Comment: @Osanosa sorry, my bad. Edited my answer. Also look at @M Ashhal solution. It's right way to implement LazyVerticalGrid

Comment: How can I make grid to show just one row? Or how to do this to a row?

Comment: @Osanosa If u want to show just 1 row, you are better using `LazyRow` instead of `LazyVerticalGrid`. Check the answer I posted, and modify it according to your needs.
For just one row, Change the extensive function from `LazyGridItemScope.ColorTile` to `LazyListScope.ColorTile` and switch from `LazyVerticalGrid` to `LazyRow`